# How to add rows as sums of other rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, aggregate

I'm not sure I titled this post correctly but I have a unique situation where I want to append a new set of rows to an existing DataFrame as a sum of rows from existing sets and I'm not sure where to start.

For example, I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Team': ['Atlanta', 'Atlanta', 'Cleveland', 'Cleveland'],
        'Position': ['Defense', 'Kicker', 'Defense', 'Kicker'],
        'Points': [5, 10, 15, 20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

        Team Position  Points
0    Atlanta  Defense       5
1    Atlanta   Kicker      10
2  Cleveland  Defense      15
3  Cleveland   Kicker      20
```

How do I create/append new rows which create a new position for each team and sum the points of the two existing positions for each team? Additionally, the full dataset consists of several more teams so I'm looking for a solution that will work for any number of teams.

***edit:*** I forgot to include that there are other positions in the complete DataFrame; but, I only want this solution to be applied for the positions "Defense" and "Kicker".

My desired output is below.

```
            Team Position  Points
        Team          Position  Points
0    Atlanta           Defense       5
1    Atlanta            Kicker      10
2  Cleveland           Defense      15
3  Cleveland            Kicker      20
4    Atlanta  Defense + Kicker      15
5  Cleveland  Defense + Kicker      35
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to create the summary rows then [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to the DataFrame:

```
df = df.append(df.groupby('Team', as_index=False).agg({
    'Position': ' + '.join,  # Concat Strings together
    'Points': 'sum'  # Total Points
}), ignore_index=True)
```

`df`:

```
        Team          Position  Points
0    Atlanta           Defense       5
1    Atlanta            Kicker      10
2  Cleveland           Defense      15
3  Cleveland            Kicker      20
4    Atlanta  Defense + Kicker      15
5  Cleveland  Defense + Kicker      35
```

We can also whitelist certain positions by filtering `df` before `groupby` to aggregate only the desired positions:

```
whitelisted_positions = ['Kicker', 'Defense']
df = df.append(
    df[df['Position'].isin(whitelisted_positions)]
        .groupby('Team', as_index=False).agg({
        'Position': ' + '.join,  # Concat Strings together
        'Points': 'sum'  # Total Points
    }), ignore_index=True
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I realized that I left out a key factor though - there will be other positions. How do I make it so this aggregation only occurs on the positions "Defense" and "Kicker" but ignores rows where the Position is equal to another value?

Comment: Just filter before groupby. See the updated codeblock

Answer (score 0):

pandas.DataFrame.append is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append) since version 1.4.0. [Henry Ecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker)'s neat solution just needs a slight tweak to use concat instead.

```
whitelisted_positions = ['Kicker', 'Defense']
df = pd.concat([df,
                df[df['Position'].isin(whitelisted_positions)]
                .groupby('Team', as_index=False).agg({
                    'Position': ' + '.join,  # Concat Strings together
                    'Points': 'sum'  # Total Points
                })],
               ignore_index=True)
```